# A reference for some fact in analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request, continuity

I am looking for a reference for the following fact. Any hints would be appreciated.

Suppose $(x_n), (y_n)\subset [0,1]$ are some sequences, $(a_n)$ is absolutely summable and for each $f\in C[0,1]$ we have

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k f(x_k) =  \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k f(y_k)$.

Then

$x_k = y_k$ for $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 4):

It's not true.  For example, if some $a_j = a_k$, you could take $(y_n)$ to be $(x_n)$ with $x_j$ and $x_k$ interchanged.